# how do i do conditional branching on a elements of a pandas series?

Tags: python, json, string, pandas, if-statement

If I have a series S that has such mixed values

```
textelement
{"id":1,"name":"whatever","value":"sonso"}
name-value
```

how do I make a conditional statement so that when the element is in JSON format, it will skip, but when it's a text string or name-value pair, I will  convert to JSON format?

Comment: Whas is desired json from filtered output from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out `json` format by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `mask` by [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['textelement',{"id":1,"name":"whatever","value":"sonso"}, 'name-value'])
print(s)
0                                        textelement
1    {'id': 1, 'value': 'sonso', 'name': 'whatever'}
2                                         name-value
dtype: object

#cast all values to string
s = s.astype(str)

#check which string starts with `{`
mask = s.str.startswith('{')

print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

print (~mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

#filter by inverted mask with ~    
s = s[~mask]

print (s)
0    textelement
2     name-value
dtype: object
```

Comment: nice, but what if I want to output all the elements in JSON after converting the text string and name-value pairs?

Comment: Then use `s1 = s[mask]`

Comment: And `s2 = s[~mask]`